# How get users who like or reply a tweet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

I have got a tweet's retweeters with `twitter` gem's method [`retweeters_of`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sferik/twitter/Twitter%2FREST%2FTweets%3Aretweeters_of) but this returns up to 100 users. Now, I need to get users who like or reply a tweet but I couldn't find the right way.

This is the way I get retweeters:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
           config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_API_KEY"]
           config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_API_SECRET"]
           config.access_token        = account.token
           config.access_token_secret = account.secret

client.retweeters_of(post_uid)
```

Comment: i didn't understand your question, the `client.retweeters_of(post_uid)` will return you the id and screen_name in JSON right?

Comment: that method returns users objects who retweeted, it's explained here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sferik/twitter/Twitter%2FREST%2FTweets%3Aretweeters_of

Comment: you can do as_json and get screen_name of the users using each_loop

Comment: yes, but about `retweeters` I already got them, the current problem is about repliers and likers.

Comment: retweet generate a new tweet id so you have to use that id to get other data, so one more each_loop

Comment: yes, but that in not the problem, `retweet` was the example which has worked for me, now I wish to get authors of `like` and `reply`

Comment: oh i understand, but i think there is no method in twitter gem to get Users who favorite a tweet

Comment: @IvánCortésRomero, did you manage to solve your problem? I'm trying to get the same information.